# What is the default mode for open() calls with O_CREAT and how to properly set it while opening/creating files

Tags: c, linux, io, system

I am trying to recreate the basic functionality of fopen() using the I/O system calls. I am somehow suppose to "set the default mode for open() calls with O_CREAT" however am unsure how to go about this. It's not perfect but this is what I've got so far.

```
MYFILE * myfopen(const char * path, const char * mode){
MYFILE *fp = (MYFILE *)malloc(sizeof(MYFILE)); //EDITED
int fd;
  switch(mode[0]){
            case 'r':
                    fd=open(path, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0440);
                    break;
            case 'w':
                    fd=open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0220);
                    break;
            default:
                    fd=open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0660);
  }

 if(fd < 0){
     return NULL;
 }

 fp->fileD=fd;
 fp->offset=0;
 return fp;
}
```

fileD will be the file descriptor returned by the open call. I think the rest is self-explanatory.

It compiles but I'm getting a "segmentation fault" error when I try to run it. This function also fails to open a new file and associate a file descriptor to it.

I think the segmentation error might be somewhere in here:

```
int myfputc(int c, MYFILE * fp){

 if(write(fp->fileD, &c, 1) == -1){
    return 1;
 }
 ++fp->offset; //how to gain access to the current offset of the stream?
 return 0;
}
```

Where I'm trying to recreate fputc.

Here is the MYFILE struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int fileD; // descriptor
    int bufferSz; // buffer size
    int bufferCh; // # of bytes in stream
    int offset; //current offset position
    int errorF; // error flag
    int EOFF; // EOF flag

} MYFILE;
```

Comment: Even a resource would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think problem is with the rest of the code, not here

Comment: I have a test file to see if it can open/create a file but this function is failing. Also I think you're correct. I think there is an issue in my recreation of the fputc function. I'm going to edit the original post.

Comment: Give the structure of MYFILE

Comment: You might also consider [`fopen_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) to avoid the race condition.

Comment: I am limited to using only the basic system calls...

Comment: Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: a open with O_CREAT and O_RDONLY will result in an empty file,

Comment: the permissions bits for some of the open calls are creating files that cannot be read by anyone.  suggest always giving the creator (at least) 0600 and then (possibly) add other bits to allow access to users in your group and in the world.  I didn't notice just which OS your using, but in *inx type systems, the actual permissions given to the file will also depend on the value in 'umask'

Comment: Right as I expect it to. Unless am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file permissions should probably be 0644, or maybe 0666 (or maybe 0640/0660 to deny others access while allowing your group access), regardless of whether you're creating the file for reading or writing.  You should not normally include execute permission (and you don't).  I'd be willing to support fewer permissions for group (no write for group seems good to me).  You can even make a file readonly for every other process while the current process has write permission with 0444 or tighter permissions.  But the standard will use 0666 and let the umask remove permissions.

You might note that your code leaks if you fail to open the file.  You should `free(fp);` before the return on the error path.

Note that you have not set all the fields in your structure, and neither has `malloc()`, so you have random junk in those fields.  Curiously, there isn't a buffer in sight, even though there's a buffer size.

---

This code works for me.  It cleans up, marginally, your `myfopen()` function, but otherwise, it runs without crashing.  I think your problem is in other code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct
{
    int fileD; // descriptor
    int bufferSz; // buffer size
    int bufferCh; // # of bytes in stream
    int offset; // current offset position
    int errorF; // error flag
    int EOFF; // EOF flag
} MYFILE;

static
MYFILE *myfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    MYFILE *fp = (MYFILE *)malloc(sizeof(*fp));
    int fd;
    switch (mode[0])
    {
    case 'r':
        fd = open(path, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0640);
        break;
    case 'w':
        fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0640);
        break;
    default:
        fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0640);
        break;
    }

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        free(fp);
        return NULL;
    }

    fp->fileD = fd;
    fp->offset = 0;
    fp->bufferSz = 0;
    fp->bufferCh = 0;
    fp->errorF = 0;
    fp->EOFF = 0;
    return fp;
}

static
int myfputc(int c, MYFILE *fp)
{
    if (write(fp->fileD, &c, 1) == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    ++fp->offset; // how to gain access to the current offset of the stream?
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    MYFILE *fp = myfopen("./test.txt", "w");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        const char *src = "The text!\n";
        while (*src != '\0')
            myfputc(*src++, fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  10 Feb 15 19:11 test.txt
$ cat test.txt
The text!
$
```

Comment: @EMMERZOH I think there could be lot more go wrong here beside permission.. may be  as answer mentioned specially in pointer handling

Comment: @EMMERZOH: Updated with working code.  I think your problem is in other code that you've not shown us.

Comment: I think you're correct. I think it has to do with the test file in terms of why my myfopen() seems to be "failing". As for the segmentation error, I assumed it was in the myfputc() function as it occurs right when this function is tested by the test file. I am at a lost as to what to do.

Comment: @EMMERZOH: Does this code work for you?  I note that it will only work on little-endian machines; the code in `myfputc()` makes unwarranted assumptions.  (If should use `unsigned char u = c & 0xFF; if (write(fp->fileD, &u, 1) != 1) ...`).  If it works as it stands, then you can add a `myfclose()`, for example.  You can also consider testing with `"r"` and `"z"` as the mode string, and work out what happens.  If you don't like the `"z"` mode, you've got some work to do in your `myfopen()` code.  You could also consider adding a `myfgetc()` function.  All this can be done without buffering.

Comment: If you're still stuck, show us the MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) code that reproduces the problem.  My `main()` is an example of MCVE code; it shows that the basics work.  You'll presumably have a slightly more complex, but not very much more complex, example that reproduces the crash you're seeing.

Comment: I have no idea where to even begin to look. I have accepted your answer as it has been the most help even though my segmentation error problem persists. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Which platform are you working on?  A  Linux variant?  Can you use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  It may point you to the right place.  Have you used the debugger?  That should identify the line where the crash occurs.  Have you added diagnostic printing (using regular standard I/O, probably on `stderr`, remembering to end printing operations with newlines so you see the printing reasonably reliably)?  What exactly is your test `main()` program doing?  What other functions of yours is it calling?  We can't debug what we can't see — we're good, but we're not omniscient.

Comment: LOL This is very true. I'm on windows but working through a linux shell.  I am going to strip it down as you suggested and add back in little bits until I find the problem. I will update in about 10 minutes. unless I crash sooner.

Comment: It looks like the problem is how the files are linked and tested (something I don't have control over), not in my code. I added my functions back in one at a time and everything worked but when I try to test it with the given test file I get the segmentation error and other "failures" according to the test code that aren't actually occurring. Thank you again and I will I could upvote you if I had enough reps @JonathanLeffler

Comment: So, there is a test harness that your code is being linked with that crashes, but you don't have the source for the test harness?  The test harness must then specify a header that tells you what your functions should look like, mustn't there?  (Surely!)  Have you been compiling with this header?  If not, why not?  Have you turned up the compiler warnings?  Have you been paying attention to and fixing all the warnings it gives?